# Calling Ember.js helper from within View.render()

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, template-engine

Is there a civilised way of calling an unbound helper from within Ember.js render()?

I am forced to rewrite a bunch of templates as raw methods for the sake of performance.

I would like to write:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helpers.action.call(someObject, ..., options);
```

but I don't know where to get the `options` from or how to construct them.

Comment: Why don't you pull the logic out of the helper, and have the helper call that logic, and then you can call that logic as well from everywhere else?  (that's if it's possible, I'm not sure what your logic is doing)

Comment: Ember.js turns out to be horribly slow for large pages. I inherited a code base that attempts to render a very long page using Ember.js templating. I have to rewrite a bunch of stuff in low level to get any kind of decent performance. My impression is that Ember generates a ton of bindings which slow everything down. I don't need that as the page is static for the most part.

Comment: Fo that reason, I don't see using templates to be a viable solutions as it's going to generate a lot of bindings. I didn't find a good way around it.

Comment: gotcha, you're aware of unbound and the group helper?  They help decrease the bindings, and htmlbars will help a ton as well in the near future...

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use that. However I ran into some bugs. Generally it seems group-helper doesn't really work with partials / other features that are more recent.